# Find the threshold value

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-science

(FF14:RR) This item can have 5 materias, 1 highlevel, 4 lowlevel.
I simplified the loops by having 3 types of materias (but i have 6, anw).
I put the materia in an item and then call Group.GetStats() to evaluate the statistics of the item then i store it in a List first checking its unicity.
Calling Group.GetStats() gives me a Dictionary with 3 caracteristics. And i want to filter the number of possibilities based on those statistics.

Example :

- Stat1 - Stat2 - Stat3
- (9, 7, 5)
- (3, 10, 5)
- (9, 7, 6)
- (8, 6, 4)
- (7, 6, 8)
- (7, 7, 7) <-
- (7, 7, 6)
- (6, 6, 5)
- (7, 6, 7)

All the tuples under (7, 7, 7) are useless because adding nothing more.

I already ended the algorithm to get all the possible materia combinations but i want to filter the combinations that are not useful.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        for (int k = j; k < 3; k++)
        {
            for (int l = k; l < 3; l++)
            {
                for (int m = l; m < 3; m++)
                {
                    ItemContainer Group = new ItemContainer(735, 400, 0, 1, 4, 864, 471, 6, new string[] { "Facet Alembic", "Facet Mortar" });
                    Group.AddMateria(new Materia(i >= 3 ? i-3 : i));
                    Group.AddMateria(new Materia(j));
                    Group.AddMateria(new Materia(k));
                    Group.AddMateria(new Materia(l));
                    Group.AddMateria(new Materia(m));
                    if (DEBUG) Console.WriteLine("{" + string.Join(",", Group.GetStats()) + "}");

                    string tempkey = string.Join(",", Group.GetStats());
                    if (i >= 3)
                    {
                        if (!unicityChecker.ContainsKey(tempkey))
                        {
                            if (isAnyBetter(Group.GetStats(),betterChecker.GetStats())) // Condition to keep it
                            {
                                ContainerList_1.Add(Group);
                                unicityChecker.Add(tempkey, Group.GetStats());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        /* 
                            find the betterChecker in order to do isAnyBetter to only get the useful items
                            */
                        if (betterChecker == null) betterChecker = Group;
                        else
                        {
                            if (isAllBetter(Group.GetStats(), betterChecker.GetStats())) betterChecker = Group;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The i < 6 sounds weird but this way i made 2 passes on the same generation of combinations.

In output of the entire algorithm (that embricks 7 of this one) i have about 10M records. I thought by removing the useless items at the first generation i could lower the size of the ouput (1Gb in json).

EDIT :

```
static bool isAnyBetter(Dictionary<String, int> stats1, Dictionary<String, int> stats2)
        {
            return stats1["craftmanship"] > stats2["craftmanship"] || stats1["control"] > stats2["control"] || stats1["cp"] > stats2["cp"];
        }
```

Comment: This is a little hard to understand, what is a threashold item, what makes it different to the others.

Comment: We won't write code for you here.  Make a serious attempt at solving the problem and if you have issues, we'll try to help.

Comment: "If any value at an index of the tuple is strictly higher than the value at the same index in threshold value, true If all values are not strictly better than the values of the threshold, false" - What???? Please spend the time to describe this in detail along with examples.

Comment: Please also post your basic algorithms - even if they didn't work - and then explain what didn't work.

Comment: @MichaelRandall i'll rephrase

Comment: @Enigmativity i explained better, thank you.

Comment: @FrankMerrow Sorry, i just didn't want to post some crap code that i wouldn't know how to explain but i did my best.